# kotlin Overload resolution ambiguity. All these functions match

Tags: kotlin

**kotlin/jvm jdk8 not support code**

```
var buffer = StringBuffer();
var arr = arrayOf("1","2","3","4");
arr.forEach {buffer::append}
```

[error info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SO6IO.png)

**java jdk8 supported code,**

```
String[] b = new String[]{"c", "b"};
Arrays.stream(b).forEach(buffer::append);
```

Comment: You might want to use `arr.forEach { buffer.append(it) }` instead

Answer (score 2):

In general, If you want to pass a method reference (`buffer::append`) to a method that takes a lambda, you need to enclose it in parentheses, not curly braces. In this specific case, you can't pass the `append` method as a method reference, because it returns `StringBuilder`, and `forEach` requires a method that returns `Unit`.

To make your code work, use a lambda:

```
arr.forEach { buffer.append(it) }
```

Comment: This code gives a compilation error: `None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied: <...> `

Comment: `Type inference failed` on `forEach`, same error as OP had on `buffer.append`. Kotlin `1.2.21`

Answer (score 1):

You can't copy-paste and use Stream code like that, because it ends up parsing it wrong. Since foreach blocks also contain the data, you can just do:

```
var buffer = StringBuffer();
var arr = arrayOf("1","2","3","4");
arr.forEach{buffer.append(it)}
```

The forEach block doesn't take a method as an argument, so doing `buffer::append` doesn't add any data, since you have to do that yourself